# Load Datatables Child from select on Parent table

Tags: asp.net, datatables

Using ASP.NET Core with Datatables populated by separate JS file.

I have a table with a row for each batch of transactions posted.
(It is a batch header with; who created the batch, when it was created etc.)

When clicking the row's View button, I want to open a 2nd table that displays all the detail transactions of the selected Batch, by passing the batchId to the 2nd table.

The following correctly passed the BatchId to the Index function of the BatchDetail controller.

```
"data": "id", 
"render": function (data) {
  return `<a href = "/Admin/BatchDetail/${data}" class="btn btn-primary" style = "cursor:pointer" >View </a>`;
}
```

The Index View then opens and loads it's JS file.
The JS file then calls the function on the controller to populate the Detail table.

```
function loadDataTable() {
{
    // DataTables
    var table = $('#datatables-column-search-text-inputs').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Admin/BatchDetail/GetAll",
        },
```

My question is, how do I access that batchId, which were passed from the BatchHeader table to the BatchDetail Index method, in this Javascript?
I would like to do something like this:

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "/Admin/BatchDetail/GetAll?batchId = batchId",
```

So I have the BatchId in the Index Method, but once the Index methods loads the View and the JS file is loaded, although I can still see the variable in the URL, I don't know how to access it.

Comment: I was wondering whether this can be achieved by using a Viewbag?

Comment: I ended up using ViewData on my Index, passing that to the View and grabbing it from my external Javascript file like so: var batchId = document.getElementById('batchId') ?
    document.getElementById('batchId').value : null;